# Android Google Maps Activity only shows small crosses

Tags: android, google-maps

I currently have a Google Map Activity which is apparently working well but doesn't show the map (this sounds stupid!)

Here is a picture that will make you understand better my problem:
[image]

I already confirmed my apiKey, checked the tutorial over and over and even the manifest seems not be missing anything.

I get only this on adb:

> 276             MapActivity  W  Recycling dispatcher 
>   com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher@43ea39b0
>
> 276             MapActivity  V  Recycling map object.
>
> 51     GpsLocationProvider  D  setMinTime 1000
>
> 276             MapActivity  I  Handling network change notification:CONNECTED
>
> 276             MapActivity  E  Couldn't get connection factory client

Does anyone have a clue about what may be causing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running the app signed with your key from your key store, or the debug key *(clicking **run** in eclipse will sign the apk with a debug key and install it on the device - be it the emulator or a physical device)*.

If you have a map key (apikey), the keystore will have two different hash codes depending on whether you use the debug key, or your key - so you need two different map keys depending how you are running the app *(the debug one will only be needed when you are developing the app).*

Take a look at the debug section: http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html#getdebugfingerprint

Comment: I'm still running it with the debug key, in the emulator. This means I don't need to associate the app now with my key, right ? I made all those steps correctly..

Comment: You will still need to get a map key for use with the debug key for the emulator. If you follow the instructions, you will need to get the MD5 hash from the debug.keystore eclipse uses. Then once you have finished your app and signed it with your own keystore, you will need a map key for that version.

Comment: But I do have the apiKey which i got from the md5 hash from the debug.keystore! Thank you for signing up for an Android Maps API key!
Your key is: .... But it never worked.

Comment: Check, and double check your key, make sure there is no white space at the end of it or the begining of your code. Alternatively make sure the point you are viewing (where your marker is) is on the map - try zooming the map right out, it could be a co-ordinate off the map.

Comment: Hey, eheh actually it was working but it was so zoomed that it couldn't show anything. (and the coordinate is wrong anyway)! Thank you for the support!

Comment: No problem, glad to have helped - I thought about the 2nd bit as I have had the same fault my self with a marker off the map!

Answer (score 2):

IF you are using `setSatellite(boolean)` and `setStreetView(boolean)` then you can face such situations. This is a BUG in Map View. Use only one of these two methods or you can try with some combinations of these two. Some times, use of only one of them solves the problem sometimes, you need to use a combination of both...like I did in my particular case..

```
streetView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        mapView.invalidate();
        mapView.setSatellite(false);
        //mapView.setStreetView(true);              
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("satelliteView", false);
    }
});

satelliteView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        mapView.invalidate();
        mapView.setStreetView(false);
        mapView.setSatellite(true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are properly setting the API key for the MapActivity/View?.  Can you post your layout xml and source code?

Make sure to follow the steps from this tutorial: http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/maps-overview.html

Answer (score 0):

It will also show a map like that if it you send it a fake lat/lon pair where there is no useful map data, eg. "geo fix 0.0 0.0" (North Pole)

Try "geo fix -0.1 51.5" (over South London) where there is Google map data.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the coordinate was wrong and that way the map was so zoomed that it wasn't able to show anything.

I zoomed out and I there was the map; so it was a coordinate problem and not a key/map activity problem.

For those who can't zoom out in these cases add this to your code

```
mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

and in the layout

```
android:clickable="true"
```